# I need to know how to do a very specific bitwise function very quickly

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am performing a bitwise function on 32- and 64-bit integers, and got stuck when writing a method (`setValueAt(index, newState)`) that sets the bit at index `index` to `1` if `newState` is `true`, or `0` if `newState` is `false`. **What bitwise function can I use to do the following operation(s) at the same speed as AND, OR, XOR, etc.?** I am hesitant to use a detecting method and then an XOR if the bit has to be changed, as this may take too much time; this method has to be called rapidly, possibly hundreds of times in succession depending on the user's activities.

```
===setValueAt(3, false)===

    0101 0001
  ? 0000 1000
==============
    0101 0001



    0101 1001
  ? 0000 1000
==============
    0101 0001
```

if it helps, the following is a truth table of the desired effect:

```
 |0|1
-+-+-
0|0|0
-+-+- 
1|1|0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void setValueAt(int &value, int pos, bool newState) {
    value = newState ? (1 << pos) | value : ~(1 << pos) & value;
}
```

Comment: if `value & 1` if O(1n), what is this?